# How do I print the outcome of a loop in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, loops, jtextarea

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestTriangle extends JFrame {

    public TestTriangle() {

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setColumns(1);
        textArea.setRows(10);
        textArea.setLineWrap(false);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        add(textArea);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestTriangle frame = new TestTriangle();
        frame.setTitle("Number Triangle");
        frame.setSize(200, 125);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the output to be a loop. Right now when I run this I just get the frame with a blank text area. I need the text area to be full of numbers in a order like this.

```
 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 etc..
```

I can't find anywhere on information about this.

Comment: Do it much the same way you might do in in the console.  Except that instead of output going to the `System.out`, send it to the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following example can help you.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TestTriangle extends JFrame {

    public TestTriangle() {

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    //textArea.setColumns(1);
    //textArea.setRows(10);
    textArea.setText(buildText());
    textArea.setLineWrap(false);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    add(textArea);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestTriangle frame = new TestTriangle();
    frame.setTitle("Number Triangle");
    frame.setSize(200, 195);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static String buildText()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            sb.append(j);
        }
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: (cough)[Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)(cough)

Answer (score 1):

This question sounds very much like homework...
Anyway, use a JScrollPane in order to allow viewing the text area.

```
JScrollPane sc=new JScrollPane(textArea);
add(sc);

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        textArea.append(j+" ");
    }
    if(i<10)
        textArea.append("\n");
}
```